# stability analysis of an ODE

Tags: stability-in-odes

I need help on how to linearize the following ODE equation so that I am able to do Stability analysis for the equation. Thanks for the help.

$\frac{dQ}{dz} = 2aM^{1/2}$

$\frac{dM}{dz} = \frac{QF}{M}$

$\frac{dF}{dz} = bQ$

Where a and b are constants. Initial points are $Q = M = 0, F = 1$ at z = 0.

Non-dimensional form of the above equation is:

$\frac{d \hat{Q}}{d\hat{z}} = \hat{M}^{1/2}$

$\hat{M}\frac{d \hat{M}}{d\hat{z}} = \hat{F}\hat{Q}$

$\frac{d \hat{F}}{d\hat{z}} = -\hat{Q}$

Case 1:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{dQ}{dz} \\
    \frac{dM}{dz} \\  
    \frac{dF}{dz}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{M^{1/2}} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{Q}{M} \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    Q \\
    M \\  
    F 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Case 2:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{dQ}{dz} \\
    \frac{dM}{dz} \\  
    \frac{dF}{dz}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{M^{1/2}} & 0 \\
    \frac{F}{M} & 0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    Q \\
    M \\  
    F 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you sure that you put everything right? For your initial values, in the second equation you have indeterminate $0/0$.

Comment: Yes actually M can not be zero. But it could be assumed that very small value.

Comment: I still do not understand. Do you mean linearization around an equilibrium?  But there are no equilibria, since by the first equation $M$ must be zero, which is incompatible with the second equation.

Comment: Yes you are right, may be if try to convert the equations into non-dimensional equations, the indeterminate might disappear.

Comment: I've done the non-dimensional form of the above equation(I wrote it above in my original question) but it doesn't make as such a difference.

Comment: Perhaps [Singular perturbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_perturbation), or [Singular perturbation theory](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Singular_perturbation_theory)?

Comment: Singular perturbation is a bit complex for me but instead for this case, I just changed the equilibrium point into (1,1,1) and  have done the linear transformation matrix in two cases. Both have the same output( Have a look above). When I check for stability by calculating the Eigen values the first one is stable but the second case is unstable. I don't understand how this difference happened. Need your help.

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ is not an equilibrium point. Analysis of stability via the signs of eigenvalues of the linearization is valid for equilibrium points only.

Comment: (1,1,1) is the value of the initial values of Q, M and F at z= 0. Still not ?

Comment: The right-hand sides of the equations at $(1,1,1)$ are not equal to zero.